# Replace end of line for lines that start with a particular pattern

Tags: vim

I have a file in the following format

```
--Some-XYZ-code ;
--Somemore--xyz--code;
COMMENT = " THIS IS A DEMO"
--somemore--code;
--somemore--code;
```

I want to put an semicolon at the end of line COMMENT, keeping the rest of the line intact.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
:g/^COMMENT/ normal A;
```

For every line that matches `COMMENT` at the beginning enter in Insert Mode at the end of the line and append a semicolon.

**Explanation**: `:g` selects every line that matches following pattern `^COMMENT` and does the action after last slash, `normal A;`

Comment: It worked.. Can you please care to explain.. or even a link will do.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
:g/COMMENT/norm A;
```

`g`: globally on all lines matching `/COMMENT/`,
`norm`: execute normal command
`A;`: of appending a semicolon to the end of the line.

Answer (score 4):

This should work

```
:%s/^COMMENT.*/&;/
```