# How do I comment all lines that match a search pattern in VIM

Tags: vim, vi

I want to comment all lines that match a particular string. I am doing assembly programming, so lines are commented using ";" character.

The string (pattern) may be present anywhere within the line. The comment should be added to the beginning of the line (obviously).

Comment: See also [Replace end of line for lines that start with a particular pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17826172).

Answer (score 16):

Alternatively:

`:g/pattern/s/^/;`

Answer (score 13):

I'd say

```
:g/pattern/norm I;
```

(assuming `;` is the comment character, and *`pattern`* is what you're looking for)

See also: [`|I|` in `insert.txt` docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#I)

Comment: I would do the same if I need comment some codes. but `I` is not bring us to the `beginning of the line` (as OP explicitly asked for) , instead, it will go to the first non-blank. There is slight difference.

Comment: @Kent that's true, and this is _exactly why_ I usually do as I posted. The introducer was meant to make this clear ("I'd say"). I'm taking the risk that my well-meant alternative angle bequeaths unappreciativeness :/ (Is it silly-word Friday yet?)

Answer (score 7):

`:s` command add a `;` to the beginning of each matched line:

```
:%s/.*pattern/;&
```

Comment: What does .* signify in the above pattern. Any documentation that can help me go understand regular expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the visual mode to select the lines on which you want to comment.
Go to the line from which you want to start the comment from.
Press shift+V - **string pattern matching** this will select the whole line.
Now press j if you want to select lines down below from the current line otherwise press k if you want to select current line + lines above.